# Is it possible to add an additional audio track to a video file in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video, avfoundation

I'm creating an app where I want the possibility to record a video(and sound), and then play it back while recording audio. After this, I'd be left with a video file (containing audio), and a separate audio file(completely different from the video's audio track).

Is it possible to use `AVMutableCompositionTrack` to compose a new video file containing one video track and two **separate** audio tracks, and then using `AVAssetExportSession` to export this to one single standalone video-file which *keeps these audio tracks separated*? What I hope to achieve with this is that the user can later watch this video-file and choose if one or both audio tracks should be playing. I know of the possibility to use multiple `AVAssets` to synchronize playback from different audio/video-files, but I'm wondering if I can create **one file** containing separable audio tracks, and then later define each audio track as an AVAsset to control the syncing.

I know some video formats/codecs etc have the ability to change audio language, even when it's only one single file. I also know `AVFoundation` has great support for handling tracks. What I don't know, is if these are compatible to each other: Can AVFoundation handle separate tracks from within one single file? And are there any codecs with support for such tracking for iOS(e.g .mp4, .mov, ...)?

I imagine "problems" would occur if a standard video player tried to watch this resulting movie-file (possibly only playing the video with the first audio track), but I'm thinking since I can already assume there are two (or more) audio tracks, it could be done?
Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: @matt Because I know this stuff from reading about it. Implement it, for the first time, would take **a lot** of time, and I thought I might save some by asking.

Comment: It wouldn't take "a lot of time" And even if it did, it is the nature of a good programmer that if something is important to you, you'll explore it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a video file with multiple audio tracks by using `AVAssetWriterInputGroup`. The [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinputgroup) says:

> Use this class to associate tracks corresponding to multiple `AVAssetWriterInput` instances as mutually exclusive to each other for playback or other processing.
> For example, if you are **creating an asset with multiple audio tracks** using different spoken languages—and only one track should be played at a time—group the inputs corresponding to those tracks into a single instance of `AVAssetWriterInputGroup` and add the group to the `AVAssetWriter` instance using the `AVAssetWriter` method `add(_:)`.

Comment: This question is over six years old, I don't even remember what this was for. Also, I'm pretty sure the goal was to play multiple audio files at the same time. Not separately, like language files.